# Failed to connect in Pod - Operation timed out when getting the response from pod

Tags: kubernetes, openshift, openshift-client-tools

Download the file https://github.com/openshift/origin/blob/master/examples/hello-openshift/hello-pod.json and execute the following commands:

```
oc cluster up
oc create -f hello-pod.json
oc get pod hello-openshift -o yaml |grep podIP
```

it will return the IP address, let say:

```
podIP: 172.17.0.6
```

Execute the command:

```
curl 172.17.0.6:8080
```

It will return **curl: (7) Failed to connect to 172.17.0.6 port 8080: Operation timed out**

Info:

```
oc v3.10.0+dd10d17
kubernetes v1.10.0+b81c8f8
features: Basic-Auth

Server https://127.0.0.1:8443
openshift v3.10.0+e3465d0-44
kubernetes v1.10.0+b81c8f8
```

Comment: Where are you executing the curl command? Inside a pod?

Comment: From the command line where I executed `oc get pod...`

Comment: I am using a macOS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your command `curl 172.17.0.6:8080` would work from inside a pod.

If you want to connect from your terminal (localhost), you have these ways:

1. `oc port-forward <pod_name> 9999:8080` and in another terminal `curl localhost:9999`, [here](https://docs.openshift.com/enterprise/3.0/dev_guide/port_forwarding.html) the command reference
2. setup an [ingress](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/)

The quickest way to debug is option 1.

Comment: We should remove `-p` from the option 1